# Read single column data from DynamoDb using lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

How can i get only single column data from dynamo db by calling lambda function in  java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using ProjectionExpression we can get single column.

```
eg:
{ 
    "TableName" : "your table name",
    "ProjectionExpression" : "column name"                        
}
```

you can use this. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html